# Why isn't my generator able to output the correct signal in a closed circuit?

Tags: waveform, signal-generator

I have a Siglent 1032X waveform generator. When I try to output a certain DC signal, my multimeter shows there's a significant voltage drop across the generator itself **in a closed circuit**. For instance, when my generator is supposed to output a 10V signal, I can barely measure 4V with my meter. In this example, the circuit is only made of the power supply and a resistance. When I just measure the voltage across the generator probes, without them being hooked up to anything at all, I get the correct output signal.

I also measured this strange phenomena across a simple resistance. My meter indicates a voltage drop across that resistance that is sometimes a fraction of the output signal.

I used a diode that I reverse biased to block the current, and this time, I measured the correct output signal across the rectifier diode so again, it seems that the problem only occurs when there's a flow of current.

I am new to Electronics, so my apologies if I phrased things in a way that was confusing. I really tried my best to be as clear as possible. Thank you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f56DSA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It sounds like you are overloading you waveform generator, can you add a schematic showing how you have things hooked up?

Comment: draw schematics or explain what you have connected on generator's output. these devices are for 50 ohm.

Comment: (1) Can you [edit] to include a link to the product manual. (2) Have you checked what the specifications say about output current capability or output impedance (resistance)? (3) What is your test load? (4) It not clear what "in a closed circuit" means. A schematic would help. There's a button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: How much load you have on the signal generator? Is it slightly below 50 ohms by any chance?

Comment: Do you understand what your signal generator's quoted output impedance of 50 ohms means? If it drives a 50 ohm load, the output will be halved. This is intentional behaviour, designed to make coaxial cables easy to use and predictable. If the load is less than 50 ohms, the output will be less than half.

Comment: If you want to verify the output of 10V signal from the generator then use a large resistor value, much greater than the typical 50 ohm source resistance, as the load resistor. Then very little current will flow and most of the output voltage will appear across the large or high impedance load resistor.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. I tried using resistors that are higher than 50 ohms and it indeed fixed the issue. You guys are awesome. Take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOmsTT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The signal generator will have a source impedance - typically 50 Ω.*

Your load creates a potential divider with the resultant drop in voltage across the source resistance, R1.

The generator is most likely designed to drive a 50 Ω load. With the 50 Ω source impedance you will need 10 V internally to get 5 V on the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5AwUX.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Driving a 50 Ω load.*

Comment: That was on point and it indeed fixed the issue. Thank you very much. Take care!

Comment: Thanks, Peet. If this answers your question then you should "accept" it to mark the question solved. If you want to wait a day or two to encourage other (maybe better) answers then that's fine.